# android app shows up in Google Play for mobiles, but not tablet

Tags: android, tablet, google-play

I have an app in Google Play (using PhoneGap) that is appearing in searches by phones, but not in searches by tablets. Any ideas why?

The Android Manifest file doesn't restrict it to any screen as far as I'm aware. Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="angelforms.kvsites.ie"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="9" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AngelFormsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check if the target is as specified as the android on phone.eg:if target is 8 to 12 and the tablet is 15. then you will have to change the target to 15 too.

Comment: Show the full manifest file. It could be that you have a `<uses-permission>` section which implies restrictions.

Comment: @KaeVerens : OK, see this documentation about "Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions For example `RECEIVE_SMS` implicity requires `android.hardware.telephony` as a 'feature'. If the tablet doesn't have a phone chip it won't be able to see the app in Google Play. The documentation shows how to use the `<uses-feature>` element to set `android:required="false"` to prevent Google Play from filtering the implied feature requirements.

Comment: thanks guys - I'm not a Java developer by trade, so am not writing the app from the ground up as I probably should. I've rebuilt the app using your pointers, though, and hopefully it will work this time!

Comment: @KaeVerens : Glad to help. The implied feature requirement when using certain permissions and the way Google Play filters apps can cause confusion for a lot of people. Just make sure you bookmark that link and refer back to it if you see similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with multiple permissions, like [RECEIVE_SMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).
You can add `required="false"` to the `uses-feature` tag to make it work.

Also, please add [`android:xlargeScreens="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) to the `supports-screens` tag to support tablets.

Comment: android:xlargeScreens="true"  this tag is not  available in menifest.Also I ma using  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> but required="false" is not appearing in menifiest .What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many thing is to consider while Making app for tablets and mobile, here is configuration setting for Application.

Hop this will hep you. Thanks.

http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-application-for-both.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. There a whole list of things that Google uses to determine if your app supports tablets.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

These are important to add to the manifest: